# Excel VBA crashing when referencing a PowerPoint slide index number

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

A couple of years ago I posted a question about an issue I was having with Excel and Powerpoint VBA on Mac OS X. I never managed to solve the problem, and instead worked around it by installing bootcamp and running it on Windows 10. However, I now have exactly the same problem again, I'd rather not use Windows, and the issue doesn't seem to have resolved itself through updates (I'm now using 365, having started with Office 2016) so I'm back here asking for help.

I have some VBA code that starts a Powerpoint session from Excel and manipulates PowerPoint using content from the Excel workbook. The problem comes whenever I try to reference a specific slide. No matter how I do it, Excel crashes. The crash always occurs at the point of making the reference to the slide index. Here's some simplified code that will trigger the crash:

```
Sub test()
Dim myApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim myPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim mySlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Set myApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set myPres = myApp.Presentations.Add
Set mySlide = myPres.Slides.Add(Index:=1, Layout:=ppLayoutTitleOnly)
Set mySlide = myPres.Slides.Add(Index:=2, Layout:=ppLayoutTitleOnly)

Set mySlide = myPres.Slides(1)

End Sub
```

That last  line before the end sub will cause the crash. This doesn't happen running on Windows. What on earth is going on?

It's incredibly frustrating. I've wasted tons of time trying to fix this, or work around it. I've seen one or two people asking similar questions elsewhere, but never seen a solution to it.

Grateful for any assistance

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is a bug which I was able to replicate. In fact `MsgBox myPres.Slides.Count` will give you `2` but it will crash on `Set mySlide = myPres.Slides(1)`. If you want to see that it is not able to recognise the newly created slides (*Though it knows there are 2 slides*) then you can use this code as well without crashing `For Each mySlide In myPres.Slides: MsgBox mySlide.Name: Next` Nor will it recognise `MsgBox mySlide.SlideNumber` or similar combinations...

Comment: There is no solution. CreateObject is an OLE call, but OLE in Office for Mac is a poorly-written mini-port of the Windows technology. I believe you can get it to work with Excel-Word combinations, but not with PowerPoint.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. If it's an OLE issue would a late binding approach work instead? I'm not fussed about performance, as it won't be run very often.

Comment: No I tested with both Early and Late Binding. It gives an error in both I will check tomorrow with Excel 2011 if it works.

Comment: Thank you - much appreciated. In the mean time, I’ve just reinstalled bootcamp / windows 10 / office 365 / Dropbox all to run one bit of VBA code, which is somewhat tedious! I think this might be the push I needed to explore other ways of automating office.